# How do I use Global instance class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

hello sorry my english is not good,I hope you can understand me..
I'm using this DbEntities and other classes everywhere
How do I use this classes global? I don't want to create continuously instance,
example Can I do this with single pattern? or global Constructor ? or What should I do?

thank you

```
 namespace Crewnetix.Entity.Concrete 
{
    public class Crew
    {
        DbEntities _DbEntities = new DbEntities (); >> object context db entities
        CertificateItem _Certificate = new CertificateItem ();
        WorldProcess _WorldProcess = new WorldProcess ();
        List<CertificateItem> _Certificates = new List<CertificateItem>();     
        CountryCity.CountryItem _Country = new CountryCity.CountryItem();

     }
}

  namespace Docnetix.Entity.Concrete
{
    public class Document
    {
        DbEntities _DbEntities = new DbEntities ();
        CertificateItem _Certificate = new CertificateItem ();
        WorldProcess _WorldProcess = new WorldProcess ();
        List<CertificateItem> _Certificates = new List<CertificateItem>();     
        CountryCity.CountryItem _Country = new CountryCity.CountryItem();

  }


  namespace accountingnetix.Entity.Concrete
{
    public class accounting
    {
        DbEntities _DbEntities = new DbEntities ();  
        CertificateItem _Certificate = new CertificateItem ();
        WorldProcess _WorldProcess = new WorldProcess ();
        List<CertificateItem> _Certificates = new List<CertificateItem>();     
        CountryCity.CountryItem _Country = new CountryCity.CountryItem();        
  }
}
```

example I want to it..I thought it

```
  namespace Global
{
    public static class GlobalInstance
    {
        public static object GetCreateInstance(object class); >> class name
        {
              ...code
            return newInstance;
        }    
    }     
  }
}

  namespace crewnetix
{
    public class crew
    {
       object instance = GetCreateInstance(CertificateItem) >> class name

    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: Well what does that class do? Are you really sure that you need it as an instance variable in each class anyway? You might be looking for the singleton pattern, but I'd discourage you from using it...

Answer (score 2):

Singleton Is perfect for your goal:

```
//1) make your constructor private

//2) add this code:

private static Your_Class_Name _Instance;
public static Your_Class_Name Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_Instance == null)
            _Instance = new Your_Class_Name();
        return  _Instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the classes static? and mark each member you also would like to be global / static , e.g:

```
public static class A 
{
  public static string GetSomething() 
  {
      // get something and return it
  }

  public static string AProperty
  {
      // getter and setter
  }
}
```

using the class;

```
A.GetSomething()
var a = A.AProperty;
```

you would not need to create an instance.